# Grid should not contain duplicate selctedItem of dropdownlist using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView which contains multiple rows. One of the columns contains a dropdownlist which in turn contains multiple items. I just want to validate that every ddl of each row should contain a unique value.
          To achieve this i have written a Jquery code. But i am finding a better solution. My code is as follows:

```
function gvDDLValidation() {
            var gvDetDDLs = $("#gvDetails").find("select[id*='ddlGrade']");
            $.each(gvDetDDLs, function () {
                var duplicateExists = false;
                var currVal = $(this).val();
                gvDetDDLs.not(this).each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == currVal) {
                        duplicateExists = true;
                        alert("Duplicate entry is not allowed");
                        $(this).focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if (duplicateExists) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing wrong with what you've got here.  That said, the way I would do this would be as follows:

1. On building the page, populate an array with the values that are entered (make the array indexes be the NAME of the controls).
2. Bind a JS function to the CHANGE EVENT for the drop down list
3. In the change event handler, check the array to see if the value exists.
4. Display error message AT THIS POINT IN TIME if error state exists

And the reason I would do this, is to get that error message to the user ASAP, and as close to the change occuring as possible.

Think of it this way, if you have 5 items in your grid, it's easy to find which drop list is duplicated. It's a different matter entirely when you have 500.